# PHP convert latin number to arabic

Tags: php, html

I need to convert all English numbers that appear in a given HTML page to Arabic with **PHP**, i tried the following code, but it convert all numbers, even inside elements. i want only convert numbers between elements. how is it?

```
function number2($srting)
{
    $Persian_Number = str_replace(
    array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'),
    array('۰','۱','۲','۳','۴','۵','۶','۷','۸','۹'),
    $srting
    );
    return $Number;
}
$html = '<div class="span5" style="margin-right: 5em;">hi 74 tnx 541 o Arabic542354</div>';
echo number2($html);
```

**DEMO:** http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1265f3cc25552e7326751c603edab9d12686be5f

This return is as: `<div class="span۵" style="margin-right: ۵em;">hi ۷۴ tnx ۵۴۱ o Arabic۵۴۲۳۵۴</div>`

I don't want it.

I want it as:`<div class="span5" style="margin-right: 5em;">hi ۷۴ tnx ۵۴۱ o Arabic۵۴۲۳۵۴</div>`

Of course, this is a small example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
function doMap($input)
{
    if (strlen($input[0]) > 1) {
        return $input[0];
    } else {
        $map = array('0' => '۰', '1' => '۱', '2' => '۲', '3' => '۳', '4' => '۴', '5' => '۵', '6' => '۶', '7' => '۷', '8' => '۸', '9' => '۹');
        return $map[$input[0]];
    }
}

function number2farsi($srting)
{
    $Persian_Number = preg_replace_callback('/\<.*?\>|[0-9]/', 'doMap', $srting);
    return $Persian_Number;
}
$html = '<div class="span5" style="margin-right: 5em;">hi 74 tnx 541 o Arabic542354</div>';
echo number2farsi($html);
```

Use regular expressions, with callback. In the code above there is regexp that catches either everything between < > chars OR any single digit. In doMap callback then we can check if this is a digit (an then map it to desired character) or is it tag (and then return it as it is).

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ae39a4daaba6456740df846d23f4b5c40d9adf62

Comment: give me this message: `preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, 'doMap', to be a valid callback`

Comment: Under what version of PHP? Did you copy all given code? It's working in demo I've posted - please check it again.

Comment: PHP Version 5.6.28 ,

Comment: @Mehdi can you post whole your code that you're trying to execute and which fails? It's clearly working in sandbox and on my PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Then you need to call the number2farsi before adding div container like below:

```
<?php
function number2farsi($srting)
{
    $Persian_Number = str_replace(
    array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'),
    array('۰','۱','۲','۳','۴','۵','۶','۷','۸','۹'),
    $srting
    );
    return $Persian_Number;
}

$text = 'hi 74 tnx 541 o Arabic542354';
$farsi = number2farsi($text);
$html = '<div class="span5" style="margin-right: 5em;">' . $farsi . '</div>';
echo $html;
```

Shorter:

```
$text = 'hi 74 tnx 541 o Arabic542354';
$html = '<div class="span5" style="margin-right: 5em;">' . number2farsi($text) . '</div>';
echo $html;
```

Comment: I knew it, What is it with html tags?

Comment: it is changing all numbers if you make the change on the entire string. so span5, 5em, all those converted. You need to make the conversion on the actual text, not on the html text to be printed on the page.